# Weighted random integers

Tags: c, math, random, weighted

I want to assign weightings to a randomly generated number, with the weightings represented below.

```
  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6
─────────────────────────────────────────
  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X
  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |   
  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |     |   
  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |     |     |   
  X  |  X  |  X  |     |     |     |   
  X  |  X  |     |     |     |     |   
  X  |     |     |     |     |     |
```

What's the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: If you move all the way to the right (i.e. to 6) no matter where you start, then 6 is always going to be visited, yes? Which means 6 will always be an outlier. Please clarify your question.

Comment: the given distribution will be created if you always pick '0'...

Comment: alternatively, describe the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than a perceieved solution...

Comment: @aecolley You're right, I should have spotted that. Amended.

Comment: I don't think what you're describing is possible.  The only weight that would uniformly distribute visits is to always select '0'.  When you select 0 you add 1 count to everything.  If you select 0 N times and 5 1 time, then you get 0,1,2,3,4 -> N, and still visited 5 more often.

Comment: @FoolishSeth You're right, I haven't described this properly. Let me just adjust the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Kerrek's answer is good.

But if the histogram of weights is not all small integers, you need something more powerful:

Divide [0..1] into intervals sized with the weights.  Here you need segments with relative size ratios 7:6:5:4:3:2:1.  So the size of one interval unit is 1/(7+6+5+4+3+2+1)=1/28, and the sizes of the intervals are 7/28, 6/28, ... 1/28.

These comprise a probability distribution because they sum to 1.

Now find the cumulative distribution:

```
P        x
7/28  => 0
13/28 => 1
18/28 => 2
22/28 => 3
25/28 => 4
27/28 => 5
28/28 => 6
```

Now generate a random `r` number in [0..1] and look it up in this table by finding the smallest `x` such that `r <= P(x)`.  This is the random value you want.

The table lookup can be done with binary search, which is a good idea when the histogram has many bins.

Note you are effectively constructing the inverse cumulative density function, so this is sometimes called the method of [inverse transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it's the inverse cumulative density function, that led me to this http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/asa241/asa241.c source code which is I think what I'm going to use.

Comment: Actually, what am I talking about, it just needs some integration. Something like 7x-(x^2)/2 = 6. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 3):

If your array is small, just pick a *uniform* random index into the following array:

```
int a[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4, 5,5, 6};
```

If you want to generate the distribution at runtime, use [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution).

Comment: The array's large, and of a length only determined at runtime.

Comment: @Alec: Added (though I'm not sure why you don't describe your constraints in the question).

Answer (score 0):

To get the distribution you want, first you basically add up the count of X's you wrote in there.  You can do it like this (my C is super rusty, so treat this as pseudocode)

```
int num_cols = 7; // for your example
int max;
if (num_cols % 2 == 0) // even
{
    max = (num_cols+1) * (num_cols/2);
}
else // odd
{
    max = (num_cols+1) * (num_cols/2) + ((num_cols+1)/2);
}
```

Then you need to randomly select an integer between `1` and `max` **inclusive**.

So if your random integer is `r` the last step is to find which column holds the r'th X.  Something like this should work:

```
for(int i=0;i<num_cols;i++)
{
    r -= (num_cols-i);
    if (r < 1) return i;
}
```