# Generation of Random Binary Numbers in C

Tags: c, random, binary

I need to randomly generate bits but the number of bits should be in a definite ratio.
Say I want to generate a 100 bits.
So if the ratio is 3:2
It has to generate 60 0s and 40 1s.
How will I be able to achieve this in C?

Comment: Look into the [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/)  function. Maybe something like `int operation = if (rand() > RAND_MAX / proportion);`?.

Comment: How about using the random functions in the standard library?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12994243/10077

Comment: What do you mean by "definite proportion"? A uniform distribution, exact equality of 0's and 1's, or a proportion other than 50/50?

Comment: *...but in definite proportion.* ... meaning exactly what? You mean you want a function that generates a binary number of 0's and 1's (the number of which you haven't specified) and the input to that function is what % of them need to be 1's? Or something else? Also, you should describe what you've tried so far to solve this problem. This site isn't a place to get people to do your work for you for free. :)

Comment: Every C implementation provides the `srand()` and `rand()` functions. In some C implementations, the low-order bit of the result of `rand()` alternates between `0` and `1`, making `rand() % 2` unsuitable. Most C implementations provide other random number generators of higher quality than `srand()` and `rand()`. See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), questions 13.15 and following.

Comment: It looks like you need a Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR), i.e. a queue of bits (usually 32 or 64) that is shifted up or down by one bit, and the vacant bit is filled with the result of a function of the bits before the shift, typically an XOR operation. These registers yield a stream of 0's and 1's with near uniform distribution. However, in a given section of the stream, you're not guaranteed to have the same number of 0's and 1's. If this is a requirement, there are tricks to force equality. But before going into the details, we need to know what distribution of values you really need.

Comment: @Nitish Makam Define what you mean by "in a definite proportion"? Something like 30% `1`s and 70% `0`s? An equal amount on average? No more deletions than insertions on average? Never more total deletions than total insertions? Or something else?

Comment: @zaph, Yes that's what I meant

Comment: @NitishMakam I offered several possibilities in the comment waht do you mean by "in a definite proportion"?

Comment: I meant Ratio. Sorry.
So if the ratio is 3:2 and say the count is 100
It needs to generate 60 0s and 40 1s and the number of 0s must always be greater than the number of 1s.

Comment: So rather than on average 3:2 you're asking for **strictly** 3:2. The easiest way to achieve that is to set the first 40 bits of an array to 1 and then shuffle it.

Comment: @NitishMakam It would be good to update the question with the ratio information, it gets lost way down here in the comments. Also consider that is there are deletions when there are no entries there will be an imbalance and the number of entries will grow.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have want a 1 with probability `p` where `p` is `double` in the inclusive range [0.0,1.0].

Then you can use this logic of `rand_bit()` below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rand_bit(double p){
    if(p==1.0){//Unusual but OK exact comparison of double.
        return 1;   
    }
    double r=((double)rand())/((double)RAND_MAX);
    return r<p?1:0;
}

//Demonstration...    

int main(void) {
    srand(78721);//Demonstration is reproducible....
    const int test=1000000;
    int count=0;
    double p=0.6;//60% 1s.
    for(int i=1;i<=test;++i){
        count+=rand_bit(p);
    }
    double prop=((double)count)/((double)test);
    printf("%f (error=%f)\n",prop,(prop-p));
    return 0;
}
```

Typical output:

```
0.600500 (error=0.000500)
```

Remember to seed the random number generator with `srand()`. Pass in a fixed value as above to get a reproducible result or `srand((int)time(NULL));` to get different results run-to-run.

Also note that the built in random number generators in C are generally not great.
They're usually fine for games, and OK for generating test cases for business applications but not usually fit for scientific simulations and cryptographically worthless.

The condition `if(p==1.0)` is there so we can be sure that `p==1.0` returns 1 always. `p==0.0` is assured by `r<p`.

Comment: It would help to provide some information on seeding or information on using a CSPRNG that does not require seeding.

Comment: @zaph I've added a further comment about `srand()`. The application doesn't appear to be about cryptography. It seems to be testing a business application in which case `rand()` will do fine.